# Is it possible to upload multiple directories storing lambda function to AWS lambda repeatedly by Loop in Terraform?

Tags: lambda, terraform, archive-file

I have 3 to 4 folders containing lambda function and related files under the same directory: functions. Those folders are archived and uploaded to AWS lambda one by one with the use of Code-Block below.

```
### Set each Lambda function's name and its path
locals {
  # Lambda Functions
  lambda_id-1            = "L1"
  lambda_source_dir-1    = "./functions/L1/"

  lambda_id-2            = "L2"
  lambda_source_dir-2    = "./functions/L2/"

  lambda_id-3            = "L3"
  lambda_source_dir-3    = "./functions/L3/"
}

### Code-Block to Zip & Upload lambda function
#########################################################################
data "archive_file" "file-preparation-1" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = local.lambda_source_dir-1
  output_path = "${local.lambda_source_dir-1}.zip"

  # Ref. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-archive/issues/39
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.dummy_trigger
  ]
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "upload-lambda-1" {
  function_name = local.lambda_id-1
  filename      = data.archive_file.file-preparation-1.output_path

  role          = aws_iam_role.lambda_upload_role.arn
  handler       = "index.handler"
  runtime       = "nodejs12.x"

  tags        = var.extra_tags,
  )

  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.file-preparation-1.output_base64sha256
  depends_on = [
    data.archive_file.file-preparation-1
  ]
}
#########################################################################
# This code-block is repeated as many times as the number of lambdas
...
```

With the above method, every time we need to upload new lambda function, we have to add more **code-blocks** for it at the bottom in addition to inserting the name and path of new lambda function into **locals**.

As we plan to increase the number of Lambda functions, I would like to change the Code-Block to be repeatedly reusable for all lambda functions by using loop, so that I won't need to add Code-Block anymore. Please help to know how to do that, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the very least, you can substantially reduce the amount of repetition that you need by using [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html) functionality.

For your case, the result would look something like

```
### Set each Lambda function's name and its path
locals {
  # Lambda Functions
  functions = {
    "L1": "./functions/L1",
    "L2": "./functions/L2",
    "L3": "./functions/L3",
  }
}

data "archive_file" "lambda_source" {
  for_each = local.functions

  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = each.value
  output_path = "${each.value}.zip"

  # Ref. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-archive/issues/39
  depends_on = [
    null_resource.dummy_trigger
  ]
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "function" {
  for_each = local.functions

  function_name = each.key
  filename      = data.archive_file.lambda_source[each.key].output_path

  role          = aws_iam_role.lambda_upload_role.arn
  handler       = "index.handler"
  runtime       = "nodejs12.x"

  tags        = var.extra_tags

  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda_source[each.key].output_base64sha256
}
```

Now to add a new function you only need to add it to the `functions` map at the top; the other two blocks don't need to be repeated.

I haven't looked at whether Terraform has functionality to build a map or array from a filesystem, so can't say whether this could be reduced further to not even need to list each function. I would personally want to see the list explicitly in the configuration anyway, but you can search further for that functionality if you want to.

Comment: Really appreciate your precise solution, it worked completely. As for the functionality to build a map in TF for the filesystem, I also think it is not necessary that the code you wrote is totally sufficient. Thanks!